# Linear Transformation $\operatorname{Im} f \neq \operatorname{Im} (f \circ f)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm learning linear algebra, specifically linear transformations, and need help with the following exercise:

> Consider the endomorphism $f: \mathbb{R^{3}} \to \mathbb{R^{3}}$ defined by $f(x,y,z) = (x+z,2x+y,3x+y+z)$ for all $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$. $(1)$ Find the matrix representation of $f$ and $f \circ f$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. $(2)$ Find a base and the dimension of the vector space $\operatorname{Im} f$. $(3)$ Explain why $\operatorname{Im} f \neq \operatorname{Im} (f \circ f)$.

Since I'm having difficulties for $(3)$ I'm going to share my work for $(1)$ and $(2)$.

$(1)$ We consider the standard basis $\mathcal{B}=\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$ of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$. Given that $f$ is a linear transformation, it can be represented by a matrix $A$ whose columns are the images of the standard basis vectors. We have

$$f(1, 0, 0) = (1, 2, 3), \quad f(0, 1, 0) = (0, 1, 1), \quad f(0, 0, 1) = (1, 0, 0).$$

Hence, the matrix representation of $f$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$
is given by

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\2 & 1 & 0\\3 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, since $f$ is represented by A, then $f \circ f$ is represented in $\mathcal{B}$ by the matrix $A⋅A$. One has

$$A^{2} = \begin{pmatrix}4 & 1 & 2\\4 & 1 & 2\\8 & 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}.$$

$(2)$ Since the set $\mathcal{B}=\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$, as a base of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$, spans $\mathbb{R^{3}}$, it follows that the set $f(\mathcal{B})=\{f(1, 0, 0), f(0, 1, 0), f(0, 0, 1)\}$ spans $\operatorname{Im} f$. We have

$$\operatorname{Im} f = \operatorname{Span}\{f(1, 0, 0), f(0, 1, 0), f(0, 0, 1)\} = \operatorname{Span}\{(1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1)\}$$ and

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\0 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Therefore $\operatorname{Im} f = \operatorname{Span}\{(1,0, 1), (0, 1, 1)\}$ and $\dim (\operatorname{Im} f) = 2$.

---

Is my work correct for $(1)$, $(2)$? Any help for $(3)$ would be appreciated. At first, I wanted to say that since the matrix representation of $f$ and $f \circ f$ are different, then $\operatorname{Im} f \neq \operatorname{Im} (f \circ f)$ but I don't think this is a good explanation (I don't even know if this is true in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At first, I wanted to say that since the matrix representation of $f$ and $f \circ f$ are different, then $\operatorname{Im} f \neq \operatorname{Im} (f \circ f)$ but I don't think this is a good explanation (I don't even know if this is true in general).

Not, that won't stick. There are lots of *different* matrices with identical images -- for example, all invertible $n\times n$ matrices have the same image. Even in one dimension, your argument wouldn't work for $f(x)=2x$ -- the matrix representations of $f$ and $f\circ f$ would be $[2]$ and $[4]$, but the image of each is all of $\mathbb R$.

"Explain" is a bit of a fuzzy word, but if you fiddle around with the eigenspaces a bit, you should be able to find a basis in which the matrix of $f$ is
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
where it is a bit easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Even though I was able to answer question $(3)$ from the hint given by Stefan4024, I'm accepting your answer since it gave me another way to understand linear transformations and clearly explained why my previous thinking was completely wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $$\dim (\text{Im}(f \circ f)) = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $A^{2} = \begin{pmatrix}4 & 1 & 2\\4 & 1 & 2\\8 & 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}$.

From this representation it is easy to see that

$\operatorname{Im} (f \circ f) = \operatorname{Span}\{(1,1, 2)\}$

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the def'n of $f.$ Notice that if $f(x,y,z)=(u,v,w)$ then $w=u+v.$ So if $z\in im(f)$ then $z=(u,v,u+v)$ for some $u, v.$

Applying the def'n of $f$  we have $f(u,v,u+v)=(r,r,2r)$ where $r=2u+v.$  So $im (f^2)\subset \{r(1,1,2):r\in \mathbb R\}$, implying $dim (im(f^2))\leq 1.$ (In fact it is equal to $1$ .)

You have already shown that $dim(im (f))=2.$ Therefore $im(f)\ne im (f^2).$